# SQL Server - DISTINCT COUNT WITH PRINTING * COLUMNS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to print all columns "*" and at the end it should display **COUNT** as **DISTINCT** and **GROUP BY SalesPersonID**

I have done many tests with sub queries and main query but it doesnt work

```
SELECT S.SalesPersonID, COUNT(*) 
FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].Store AS S
GROUP BY S.SalesPersonID
```

This query gives me accurate counts but I intend to print more columns and as soon as I enter another column the query wont work which I believe it is a GROUP BY SELECT Statment.

How would you do this please.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MySQL and not SQL Server?

Comment: i changed the tag into SQL instead for a more general ANSI SQL statement.. the brackets indicate your are using SQL Server (MSSQL) and not MySQL which @LukaszSzozda already said.. also i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide us with text formatted example data and expected results.. And provide us the correct database system.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL 8.0/SQL Server support windowed `COUNT(*)`

```
SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY S.SalesPersonID) AS cnt
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.Store AS S
```

Comment: Yes but brackets ( `[]` ) isn't valid MySQL syntax it's SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Based on Database name I am 95% sure it is SQL Server

Comment: Yes but if you remove the brackets it's all of the sudden valid ANSI SQL and will run on MySQL 8.0 and SQL Server without problems ..

Comment: Hey I am a noob lol I thought it looked cooler so i used brackets haha. anyways thanks for the knowledge and yea it perfectly works. .....SELECT *,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY S.SalesPersonID) AS cnt
FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.Store AS S  ........ is correct tysm